# How to get a product information from Magento Community Edition 1.6

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, magento

I am developing an application to export sales orders from Magento (Community Edition 1.6) to Quick Books.

I am using Magento's SOAP API to retrieve the sales orders. When importing products from Magento into Quick Books I noticed that it does not accept product names longer than 31 characters.

There is an option in Magento to create a name for the product (max. 31 characters) which can be imported into Quick Books. However, I don't know the API to retrieve that secondary product name. Can anyone help me out or point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I assume the secondary name for your products (max. 31 characters) is a custom attribute? In that case, check out: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/retrieving-product-attributes-from-magentos-v2-api which shows how to retrieve product attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : [Magento Core API - Product attributes API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#product_attributes_api)

Comment: I tried with catalogProductAttributeOptions method and CalogProductInfo method.Both are need String 'Store View' parameter.what is store view.In Magento there are three options available to select the scope(Global,Website,Store View).Whatever i give is throwing exception that " produc not exist".What to give in store view parameter field?